# Blur the border of an Image

Tags: css

My question is how can I blur only the border of an image?
The image itself should not be blured, just the border.

EDIT: done..thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your comments on Sagar Kodte's answer, is this what you wanted?

```css
img {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
```

I added a border of 2px to the images and a box shadow.

**"Out there" idea:**

I'll preface this by saying [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) are coming in fast but are not [everywhere](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) yet (Just IE lagging behind I think).

That being said I think they are a wonderful idea and will put this answer here just so you know of their existence.

```css
.red {
  --border-color: #900;
}
.green {
  --border-color: #090;
}
.blue {
  --border-color: #009;
}
.clown {
  --border-color-top: green;
  --border-color-right: yellow;
  --border-color-bottom: red;
  --border-color-left: blue;
}
img {
  border-top: 2px solid var(--border-color-top, var(--border-color, #000));
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--border-color-bottom, var(--border-color, #000));
  border-right: 2px solid var(--border-color-right, var(--border-color, #000));
  border-left: 2px solid var(--border-color-left, var(--border-color, #000));
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 10px -1px var(--border-color-top, var(--border-color, #000)), 4px 0 10px -1px var(--border-color-right, var(--border-color, #000)), 0 4px 10px -1px var(--border-color-bottom, var(--border-color, #000)), -4px 0 10px -1px var(--border-color-left, var(--border-color, #000));
  margin: 10px;
}
.img {
  border: 2px solid var(--border-color, #000);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--border-color, #000);
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<b>Standard:</b>
<br>
<img src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
<br>
<b>Single color:</b>
<br>
<img class="red" src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
<img class="green" src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
<img class="blue" src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
<br>
<b>Mulitple colors:</b>
<br>
<img class="clown" src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
```

Comment: It´s kinda, but if I want other border-colors, let´s say: border: 3px solid; border-bottom-color: red; border-top-color: green; border-left-color: blue; border-right-color: yellow; box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
and now can you see my problem? I think I have to blur the borders somehow...

Comment: Give this a look, it's not supported in IE or Edge though.

Comment: Wow okay that´s awesome! And now an extra task would be to have 4 different colored borders....hmm any ideas..? :)
Thank you!

Comment: @dipsi as in another box with another color? Or one box with several colors?

Comment: border-bottom-color: red;
border-top-color: green;
border-left-color: blue;
border-right-color: yellow;

So one box with four colors..

Comment: @dipsi then it gets a little more complex but it's still doable.

Comment: Your awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using box-shadow property like below

**TIP:** you need to match the shadow color to your background or image border for the desired effect.

```css
.image-blurred-edge {
    background-image: url('http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg');
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px #fff inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-blurred-edge"></div>
```

Using `img` tag you have to use pseudo element that is `:before`

```css
.shadow
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.shadow:before
{
    display:block;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 8px 4px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 8px 4px #fff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 8px 4px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
            <img src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Considering your last comment Try this solution.

```css
.shadow img{
  border:2px solid #000;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 10px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
      <img src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: It should be an normal <img> tag and not a background image...have you another solution?

Comment: @SagarKodte It's slightly harder with image tags, something like this might work https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/1rjz8zab/

Comment: hm, wait maybe I failed to explain that properly :) 
I need a border (border: 2px solid black) around my image & I would like that the border is blured. But I really appreciate that, thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<img class="borderBlur" src="http://visitwabashcounty.com/wp-content/uploads/6056710418_03fda4569b_z-150x150.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
.borderBlur {
      border: 2px solid #000;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you wrap the image in a div you can apply a box-shadow to that.

It will appear *under* the image to start, so you need to apply a lower `z-index` to the image

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 4px 4px black;
}
img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/284/196" alt="" />
</div>
```